# Gas Station Dynamic Programming

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

You and your friends are driving to Tijuana for springbreak. You are saving your money for the trip and so you want to minimize the cost of gas on the way. In order to minimize your gas costs you and your friends have compiled the following information. First your car can reliably travel m miles on a tank of gas (but no further). One of your friends has mined gas-station data off the web and has plotted every gas station along your route along with the price of gas at that gas station. Speciﬁcally they have created a list of n+1 gas station prices from closest to furthest and a list of n distances between two adjacent gas stations. Tacoma is gas station number 0 and Tijuana is gas station number n. For convenience they have converted the cost of gas into price per mile traveled in your car. In addition the distance in miles between two adjacent gas-stations has also been calculated. You will begin your journey with a full tank of gas and when you get to Tijuana you will ﬁll up for the return trip. You need to determine which gas stations to stop at to minimize the cost of gas on your trip.

Sample Input:

Prices (cents per mile)
[12,14,21,14,17,22,11,16,17,12,30,25,27,24,22,15,24,23,15,21]

Distances (miles)
[31,42,31,33,12,34,55,25,34,64,24,13,52,33,23,64,43,25,15]

Your car can travel 170 miles on a tank of gas.

My Output:

Minimun cost for the trip is: $117.35

Gas stations to stop at: [1, 6, 9, 13, 17, 19]

I have already solved the problem, but I am not sure if I have done it the right way. Would someone please give me some suggestion or point me to a right direction if it is wrong? Thank you in advance.

```
public class GasStation {

/** An array of gas prices.*/
private int[] myPrice;
/** An array of distance between two adjacent gas station.*/
private int[] myDistance;
/** Car's tank capacity.*/
private int myCapacity;
/** List of gas stations to stop at to minimize the cost.*/
private List<Integer> myGasStations;


/**
 * A constructor that takes in a price list, distance list, and the car's tank capacity.
 * @param thePrice - price list
 * @param theDistance - distance list
 * @param theCapacity - the car's capacity
 */
public GasStation(final int[] thePrice, final int[] theDistance,
        final int theCapacity) {
    myPrice = thePrice;
    myDistance = theDistance;
    myCapacity = theCapacity;
    myGasStations = new ArrayList<>();
}


/**
 * Calculate for the minimum cost for your trip.
 * @return minimum cost
 */
public int calculateMinCost() {

    int lenP = myPrice.length;
    int lenD = myDistance.length;
    if (lenP == 0 || lenD == 0 || myCapacity == 0) return 0;

    // gas station -> another gas station (moves) 
    Map<Integer, Integer> gasD = new HashMap<>();
    int[] D = new int[lenD + 1];
    D[0] = 0;

    // calculate the total distance 
    for (int i = 0; i < lenD; i++) {
        D[i + 1] = D[i] + myDistance[i];
    }

    int len = D.length;
    for (int i = 1; i < len - 1; i++) {
        int j = len - 1;
        while (D[j] - D[i] >= myCapacity) {
            j--;
        }
        gasD.put(i, j - i);
    }

    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        int temp = 0;
        int cur = i;
        List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (D[i] <= myCapacity) {
            temp = D[cur] * myPrice[cur];
            tempList.add(cur);
            int next = gasD.get(cur) + cur;
            while (next < len) {
                temp += (D[next] - D[cur]) * myPrice[next];
                cur = next;
                tempList.add(cur);
                if (gasD.containsKey(cur)) next = gasD.get(cur) + cur;
                else break;
            }

            if (temp < min) {
                min = temp;
                myGasStations = tempList;
            }

        }
    }


    return min;
}

/**
 * Get gas stations to stop at.
 * @return a list of gas stations to stop at
 */
public List<Integer> getGasStations() {
    return myGasStations;
}
```

}

Comment: it looks too long, in my opinion it is much simpler. so did you get the total cost of `11735 cents` for the one-way trip from Tacoma to Tijuana? I got `7489 cents` and stops at gas stations `[1, 6, 9, 11, 15, 19]`

Comment: refill `31 miles` at `station 1` for `14 cents/mi`, refill `152 miles` at `station 6` for `11 cents/mi`, refill `114 miles` at `station 9` for `12 cents/mi`, refill `88 miles` at `station 11` for `25 cents/mi`, refill `121 miles` at `station 15` for `15 cents/mi`, and finally arrive at `station 19`

Comment: total cost is `(31 * 14) + (152 * 11) + (114 * 12) + (88 * 25) + (121 * 15) = 7489 cents`. and I assumed that we don't need to count the cost of a full tank (which is `170 * 12`) at `station 0` (the starting point). well, even if I count it, the cost is still less than yours. If you're curious, I may post a reply below with the method I used

Comment: if we refill at `station 19` for the return trip, it costs `147 mi * 21 cents/mi` which is `3087`, making total cost of `7489 + 3087 = 10576`, again less than your result

Comment: You are right! I made a change to my codes since then, and I got a much better cost but it is still not the optimal solution like the result you have. Do you have a section in my codes that would you recommend to fix, and better the algorithm? Thank you!

Comment: I've posted my version below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let the minimal cost of refill at `station i` be denoted as `cost[i]`

Given the problem statement, how can this cost be expressed?
We know that every next refill has to be done within `170 miles` away from the last refill,
so the minimal cost could be expressed as follows:

`cost[i] = MIN { cost[j] + price[i] * distance_from_i_to_j } for every j such that distance(i,j) <= 170 mi`

with base case `cost[0] = 0` if we don't consider the full tank cost at `station 0`, otherwise the base case is `cost[0]= 170 * price[0]`

I will assume that we don't consider the full tank cost at `station 0`, and that there is no refill needed at the final point i.e. `station 19`

By looking at the recurrence relation defined above, we may easily notice that the same subproblem is called more than once which means that we may utilize dynamic programming solution in order to avoid possibly exponential running time.

Also note that since we don't need to refill at `station 19`, we should calculate the costs of refilling at stations `1` through `18` only, i.e. `cost[1], cost[2], .., cost[18]`. After doing that, the answer to the problem would be `MIN { cost[14], cost[15], cost[16], cost[17], cost[18] }` because the only stations located within 170 miles away from `station 19` are stations `14,15,16,17,18` so we may reach station `19` by refilling at one out of these 5 stations.

After we have defined the above recurrence relation with base case, we may convert it into the loop in the following way:

```
int price[] =  {12,14,21,14,17,22,11,16,17,12,30,25,27,24,22,15,24,23,15,21}; //total 20 stations

int distance[] = {31,42,31,33,12,34,55,25,34,64,24,13,52,33,23,64,43,25,15};  //total 19 distances      

int N=19;
int[] cost = new int[N];    
int[] parent = new int[N]; //for backtracking

cost[0] = 0; //base case (assume that we don't need to fill gas on station 0)

int i,j,dist;
int maxroad = 170;

for(i=0; i<N; i++) //initialize backtracking array
    parent[i] = -1;


for(i=1; i<=N-1; i++) //for every station from 1 to 18
{

        int priceval = price[i]; //get price of station i               
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;                
        dist = 0;            

        for(j=i-1; j>=0; j--) //for every station j within 170 away from station i
        {   
            dist += distance[j]; //distance[j] is distance from station j to station j+1
            if(dist>maxroad)
               break;   

            if((cost[j] + priceval*dist)<min) //pick MIN value defined in recurrence relation                       
               {
                min = cost[j] + priceval*dist;
                parent[i] = j;
               }

        }

        cost[i] = min;              

}


//after all costs from cost[1] up to cost[18] are found, we pick
//minimum cost among the stations within 170 miles away from station 19
//and show the stations we stopped at by backtracking from end to start

int startback=N-1;
int answer=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
i=N-1;
dist=distance[i];
while(dist<=maxroad && i>=0)
{
   if(cost[i]<answer)
      {
       answer = cost[i];
       startback=i;
      }  
   i--;
   dist += distance[i];
}


System.out.println("minimal cost=" + answer + "\nbacktrack:");

i=startback;
while(i>-1) //backtrack
{
    System.out.println(i + " ");
    i = parent[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. I have solved the problem using shortest path algorithm, but I will give your solution a try and see if I I get the same result.

Comment: @mangusta Great solution. But I'm confused. Let's say i is 5, j is 3, then for min of cost[5] we consider cost[3] + (dist b/w 3-5 * price[5]) as a candidate. But the price at which fuel is bought at station 5, that is never used to travel from 5 towards 3, as we are moving forward towards station 19, so whatever I buy at 5, will be used to go towards stations 6,7,8... Then how is this approach working? Basically why do we calculate cost at i by taking distances from previous stations (0 <= j< i) and multiply by price[i], when that fuel is being used to go to indexes greater than i. Please Help

Comment: @JohnDoe `cost[5]` only reflects the *cost of getting to 5* and not further, it does not include the cost of getting to 6,7,8 etc. On the other hand, the cost of 6,7,8 may (or may not) include the cost of getting to 5, which in turn may (or may not) include the cost of getting to 1,2,3,4. It is simply a recursion

Comment: @mangusta Thanks much for replying :), what you said makes perfect sense, I'm a bit slow. I am still somewhat confused, let's say distance between 5 and 3 is 10 miles and price[5] is 8, then you add 8*10 as well in one of the candidates for minimum cost[5], how is this factor of 80 leading to correct answer finally when I'll never cover these 10 miles at the price of 8, because price is 8 at fifth station and this 8*10 is for 10 miles before station 5. Please help in explaining. I was thinking let's say at station 3 my cost is 250, and station 5 is 10 miles, then refill 10*price[3] to reach 5

Comment: @JohnDoe during the journey from `j` to `i` the car spends a certain amount of gas equivalent to `distance_from_i_to_j` which is refilled at station `i` for `price[i]`. we pick the cheapest refill out of the possible options (i.e. stations located within 170 miles from `i`)

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting, but I am reasonably sure this answer is incorrect! It assumes that when we stop at a gas station that we fill the tank completely.

We can look at a simple example where this doesn't work. If we take the first two cities to be 170 mi apart, then the next one to be 1 mi, and the one after to be 1 mi, and the prices as [100,1,100] we have a refill at station 1 but only need one gallon to make it to the next station. So we can get to the end with 101 dollars. The solution above gives 100*170=17000 (refill at first stop) as the answer

Comment: @DamienMartin you're right, i considered complete refill. If we want to refill partially, we can go from right to left (hence i < j), and basically use the same formula, with only difference that cost[i] = MIN { cost[j] + price[i] * (dist(j) - dist(i)) } and goal state will be cost[0]