# Minimum cost to travel from 1 city to another in a graph. (Not dijkstra's algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm

Bob is living in Oiland, which has N cities numbered from 1 to N and M roads connecting these cities. He wants to visit city B to meet Alice, from city A, where he lives. It is a long trip and Bob will stop at multiple fuel stations to refuel hi car.
The price of fuel is different at different stations and Bob is ready to take detours to visit a station with lower price. Bob has a map which has N cities and S fuel stations marked on it. From the map he knows how much fuel in litres is needed to travel between two cities and price per litre at each fuel station. Also car's fuel tank has maximum capacity C litres. Write a program to find minimum amount to spend to travel from city A to B. He starts with empty fuel tank and there is a fuel station at city A.

```
Constraints:
2 <= N cities <= 1000
1 <= M connecting roads <= 10000
1 <= S fuel stations <= 120
1 <= C fuel tank capacity <= 100000
1 <= G fuel needed to travel between any 2 cities <= 100000
```

I am unable to solve it. If anybody could give its solution or tell some hints to solve it, it would be helpful.

Comment: Any example...?

Comment: This looks like a problem from a programming competition. Please don't ask questions about ongoing competitions. If the competition has finished, please provide a link to it.

Comment: I am not that much involved in programming algorithms, but I think A* algorithm may suit your purpose?

Comment: @YashShah Consider the following example:- N = 5, M = 5, S = 3,  C = 1000 litres, A = 1, B = 5. The edges are: (1, 2, 800), (2, 5, 800), (4, 5, 600), (3, 4, 600), (1, 3, 400). The edges are of form (start, end, fuel required in  litres to travel from start  to end). All edges are undirected. The fuel stations are: (1, 80), (2, 90), (3, 20) where (i, j) means city i has fuel station with price j units/litre. In this scenario the optimal solution is 1-->2-->5 with total amount of 134000. The route 1->3->4->5 is not feasible since fuel required for path 3->4->5 exceeds C.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. this question is not from ongoing contest. Also i didn't participte in the contest so i don't have it's link because it's asked by a company in its recruiting test in some other college.

Comment: @Vishal Ok i will look at A* algo, thanks for replying

Comment: A* won't really work any better than say Dijkstra. At each pump you need to decide not only where to go next, but how much fuel to buy. This makes the search space rather large for normal shortest path algorithms.

Comment: Hi I believe you found this in the Goldman Sachs Mock test #2 It has been solved before, here are the links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53357989/gas-station-dynamic-programming https://silo.tips/download/to-fill-or-not-to-fill-the-gas-station-problem-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At each pump the driver needs to decide not only where to go next, but how much fuel to buy.

The following is an untested idea that may or may not work.

This problem can be solved by a modified smallest-weight-path algorithm, say Dijkstra's. We need to modify the notion of weight. In our case it is not a single number, but a *function*, specifically, the function that maps the amount of fuel left in the tank to the amount of money spent. To make a specific example, consider a single edge from the origin A to the nearest pump X. Say the distance is 100 km, fuel consumption is 10l/100km, the price of fuel at A is $2/l, and the tank can take 50l. The driver can buy anywhere from 10 to 50l to get from A to X, so the weight of AX edge is a piecewise linear function defined on the interval 0..40, taking the value of $20 at 0 and $100 at 40.

Now if the driver continues from X to Y, the normal algorithm would add the weight so far to the weight of the edge. But we have two functions for weights, one is piecewise-linear monotonically-increasing (the weight so far) and the other is a single-segment piecewise-linear (the weight of the outgoing edge). We need to combine the two in the following way. Shift the first function left by the amount of fuel needed to get from X to Y, discard the negative part, add the corresponding price. For the remaining part of the function graph, consider price of the fuel that corresponds to each segment. If the fuel is more expensive locally, leave the segment as is; if it is cheaper locally, recompute the segment; if the segment represents an empty tank, top up for local price.

Another, perhaps easier way to look at this operation is to imagine a list that looks like this: "At this point I may have up to x1 litres of fuel at price p1 per litre, and also up to x2 litres of fuel at price p2, and..." When you arrive at a gas station, drop all items in the list that are more expensive than the local price, and top up.

Now when the normal algorithm considers two paths leading to the same vertex, it needs to decide which weight is better. Since the weight is now a function, the modified algorithm needs to take the minimum of the two functions, which will be another function, again piecewise-linear.

So you have monotonically-increasing piecewise-linear function at each vertex of the graph; each point of the function graph corresponds to the cheapest way to get to that vertex with given amount of fuel left.

Your final solution is the value of your function at 0 in the destination vertex.